# mod rewrite what and where to place

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I used mod rewrite (.htaccess) to:

1. send `/index.file` to `/`
2. send non-www to www

Now I want to rename my web pages from `/2.html` to `/words.html`, `/3.html` to `/text.html`, etc.

```
RewriteRule ^old\.html$ new.html  [R=301, L]   --possible script?
```

What is the best way to do this with a **301 redirect/rewrite(?)**, and **what is the order**, i.e., I know the above two are in the correct order--but where are these new redirects/rewrites placed? (First or after #1 & 2.)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the `Redirect` directive

```
Redirect permanent /one http://example.com/two
```

Put it in your .htaccess file.
[See explanation here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).

Answer (score 0):

Just append these lines to your existing .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^2\.html/?$ /words.html [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^3\.html/?$ /text.html [R=301,NC,L]
```